# When training tensorflow, reducing the batch size does not change the GPU memory

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

When training tensorflow, reducing the batch size does not change the GPU memory.

Server specifications

- OS : Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
- GPU : TITAN RTX
- NVIDIA Diriver : 525.125
- CUDA : 11.8
- Cudnn : 8.6.0
- Python : 3.8
- tensorflow : 2.12

When training in tensorflow, changing the batch size from 8 to 32 or from 8 to 4 does not change the GPU memory from 17G.
Naturally, we are setting

```
tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True)
```

GPU memory increase/decrease with batch size changes